# Ihara zeta function and closed paths and trails

Tags: graph-theory, random-walks, zeta-functions

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite graph. There seem to be two definitions of *closed path* in the literature. In one, a closed path is just a walk whose starting vertex is the same as the ending vertex. (Let us call that a *closed walk*.) In the other one, which we will follow, a closed path is a closed walk visiting vertices $v_0, v_1,\dotsc,v_k=v_0$ with all $v_i$ distinct (except perhaps $v_k=v_0$.) Let us follow the second definition.
A closed trail is a closed walk that does not repeat edges.

A *closed geodesic* is a closed walk without backtracking or tails, i.e., $v_i\ne v_{i+2 \mod k}$ for all $i$, where $k$ is the length of the path, just as above. A closed geodesic is said to be *prime* if it is not equal to another closed geodesic repeated $d\geq 2$ times.

The Ihara zeta function is defined to be
$$\zeta_\Gamma(z) = \prod_{[P]} (1- z^{|[P]|})^{-1},$$
where $[P]$ runs over all prime closed geodesics. Here $|[P]|$ is the length of $P$.

Is it possible to write $\zeta_\Gamma(z)$ as a product over (some) closed paths of given lengths (following the second definition)? Is it possible
to write it as a product over closed trails?

Comment: I think I had a similar thought/problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1580353/19341)...

Comment: What's the difference between closed trails and a closed geodesics? If you don't allow backtracking and tails, you won't repeat vertices or edges...